# How to render in real-time the django model's field using django channels?

Tags: javascript, python, django, real-time, channel

I already set up the connection between the server side which are the asgi.py, consumers, and routing, that is already listening to client side using javascript. But I don't know how to render out, in real time, the field in that one model to my javascript that'll will be shown in HTML.

This is the JavaScript:

```
var socket = new WebSocket(`ws://${window.location.host}/orders/`);

  socket.onmessage = function (e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    document.getElementById("testingMessage").innerText = data.message;
  };
```

This is the consumers.py so far:

```
class OrderConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()
        await self.send(json.dumps({'message':"testing"}))

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.disconnect()
```

And this is the routing.py:

```
from . import consumers
from django.urls import path

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('time/', consumers.OrderConsumer.as_asgi())
]
```

This is the models.py model:

```
class BillingAddress(models.Model):

    isComplete = (
        ('NO', 'NO'),
        ('YES', 'YES'),
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    full_name = models.CharField(default='', null=True, max_length=1000)
    contact_number = models.CharField(default='', null=True, max_length=1000)
    full_address = models.CharField(default='', null=True, max_length=1000)
    message = models.CharField(default='', null=True, max_length=1000)

    total_price = models.CharField(default='', null=True, max_length=1000)

    is_complete = models.CharField(choices=isComplete, null=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.full_name:
            self.slug = slugify(self.full_name)
        super(BillingAddress, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

All I want to achieve is to render that one field from the model (full_name) through the HTML in real time. Whenever there's a new user registered, I want it to be rendered in real-time through the html.